# How to create group based access in superset with integration of key cloak

Tags: keycloak, apache-superset, keycloak-services

Currently we have integrated superset with key cloak, we have a requirement to create groups to access the dashboards like as below.

[image]

When user 1 login into the superset (through key cloak) he/she should able to see the dashboard 1,2 similarly when user3 login then only dashboard 3 should be visible.

How we can achieve this in superset, what are all the code changes we need to in superset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With superset this way full of pain and suffering :)

This work for us, Superset version 2.0.0

You need customize SupersetSecurityManager
Our example in helm chart:

```
configOverrides:
  enable_oauth: |
    ...
    from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
    from custom_sso_security_manager import CustomSsoSecurityManager
    CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager
    AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
    ...
```

To override method

```
def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        # Keycloak provider
        if provider == 'keycloak':
            logging.debug('Get userinfo...')
            # path below may depend from you Keykloack config
            resp = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('https://[your Keykloack OIDC provider]/auth/realms/[name Oauth]/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo')
            logging.debug('Resp received: {0}'.format(str(resp)))
            me = resp.json()
            logging.debug('user_data: {0}'.format(me))
            groups = me.get('groups')
            # transform groups as you need
            ...
            return {
                'name': '{} {}'.format(me['given_name'], me['family_name']),
                'email': me['email'],
                'username': me['email'],
                'first_name': me['given_name'],
                'last_name': me['family_name'],
                'kk_groups': groups
            }
```

Then you need to override and modify method auth_user_oauth and build your own roles for every group in Keycloack in method build_your_own_roles

You need to copy-paste code of auth_user_oauth as is from suorce and just modify role building.

Sorry for formatting, some tabs could be wrong aligned :)

```
import logging
from typing import List

from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager

class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSsoSecurityManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def auth_user_oauth(self, userinfo):
        ...

        # Sync the user's roles
        if user and self.auth_roles_sync_at_login:
          user.roles = self.build_your_own_roles(userinfo)
          logging.debug(
              "Calculated new roles for user='{0}' as: {1}".format(
                  username, user.roles
             )
         )

        # If the user is new, register them
        if (not user) and self.auth_user_registration:
           user = self.add_user(
              username=username,
              first_name=userinfo.get("first_name", ""),
              last_name=userinfo.get("last_name", ""),
              email=userinfo.get("email", "") or f". 
               {username}@email.notfound",
              role=self.build_your_own_roles(userinfo),
        ...

        def build_your_own_roles(self, userinfo) -> List:
           
           kk_roles = []
           for role in userinfo.get('kk_groups'):
               kk_roles.append(self.add_role(role))
           
           # If need add Gamma and sql_lab roles for access to own charts and dashboards
           kk_roles.append(self.find_role('Gamma'))
           kk_roles.append(self.find_role('sql_lab'))
           return kk_roles
```

Then you need to enable DASHBOARD_RBAC feature

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
...
    'DASHBOARD_RBAC': True,
...
}
```

And finally you must set role to access to dashboard which equal name group in Keycloack